# What is the meaning of Duration in Amazon RDS Backup window

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-backup

What does **Duration** specify?

Does it mean that the backup will start between 01:00 to 01:30 and keep running until it has completed? Or does it have a different meaning?

[image: RDS Backup]

Answer (score 0):

The duration window indicates the time in which the backup will start. I can start anywhere between the time specified and could last longer than the window.